# best tool for this case?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I'm an Oracle Developer. The only programming language that I know is PL/SQL, 
and I want to develop an application and upload it to Google Play and Apple's App Store so that it's available for download, and it should work offline.

Oracle Developer cannot deal with mobile apps, but there is Oracle Apex, and I can do a workaround, but it's hard and it cannot work offline.
The application is very small (just 5 or 6 pages and tables).

I want your help to pick up a programming language and tools with which I can do my task in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

Go with [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). With PhoneGap you create apps using the web technologies you know and love: `HTML`, `CSS`, and `JavaScript`.

Comment: By phonegap you can able to develop application for both platform i.e android and iOS

Comment: Ionic framework with cordova is best if you know HTML, CSS, JavaScript